# JFreeChart TimeSeries array exception

Tags: java, arrays, time-series, jfreechart

this is my first question here ever, and I would appreciate if you can help me.

Since the code I have is way too large to post here, I'll try to describe what my problem is in short.

So, I have made TimeSeries array within my class and array list from where I get values for time series:

```
private TimeSeries[] seriesArray = new TimeSeries[10];
ArrayList<TempClass> valuesFromArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I need to make TimeSeries array, because I want to be able to show multiple timeseries graphs. Using only one TimeSeries and addOrUpdate method isn't what I want because then values get mixed when I create more graphs. So, I add values like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < valuesFromArrayList.size(); i++)
{
    TempClass obj = (TempClass) valuesFromArrayList.get(i);
    int timeStamp = obj.getTimeStamp();
    int hrsDiff;
    int minsDiff;
    int secsDiff;

    hrsDiff = timeStamp / 3600;
    timeStamp = timeStamp - hrsDiff * 3600;
    minsDiff = timeStamp / 60;
    timeStamp = timeStamp - minsDiff * 60;
    secsDiff = timeStamp;

    seriesArray[Integer.parseInt(comboBoxValue) - 1].add(new Second(secsDiff, minsDiff, hrsDiff, day, month, year), Math.abs(obj.getValue()));
}
```

What this part of code does is that it reads values and timestamps from ArrayList I created. There is comboBox where user can choose which timeSeries array index will be in graph. So, if user chooses value 9 from comboBox, timeSeries from index 8 will be chosen and plotted on graph. TimeStamp is simply number of seconds that passed since 00:00:00 at day when values were taken.

TempClass is defined as:

```
class TempClass
{
    private int timeStamp;
    private double value;

    public TempClass(int a, double b)
    {
        timeStamp = a;
        value = b;
    }

    public int getTimeStamp()
    {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public double getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double val)
    {
        value = val;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I try to make second (2nd) graph, that is another index of TimeSeries array, I get message:

```
You are attempting to add an observation for the time period Thu Apr 30 00:00:00 CEST 2015 but the series already contains an observation for that time period. Duplicates are not permitted.  Try using the addOrUpdate() method.
```

I don't want to use addOrUpdate method, I need add method. Values in ArrayList I use to put values into timeSeries are fine, I am 300% sure. I already checked input from comboBox value and it gives correct values.

I have no explanation other that for some reason, even if array index is changed, data I want to write into the series goes to the old series (that is, to the series at the old index). In other words, it seems like even if I change index of array, it keeps writing into the old array index!

It's like equivalent to this (I know this sounds crazy but that is basically what I am getting):

```
int[] array = new int[5];
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
System.out.println(array[0]);

And the output I get is
2
```

This is something I have never heard of before, and I have code similar to this I wrote here in two other places, and in that two places it goes just fine, but in this third place I keep getting that exception.

Is this some kind of bug in JVM?

Does somebody know what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about TimeSeries, but after skimming the docs about it it says:

> "The time series will ensure that (a) all data items have the same
>   type of period (for example, Day) and (b) that each period appears at
>   most one time in the series."

[Link to Docs](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html)

I'm guessing the error is pretty straight forward or a misuse of TimeSeries. It looks like you are simply adding a duplicate date and that the constraints of TimeSeries don't allow that. 
   You may wish to consider writing a custom class that has the functionality you want. Yet again, I don't know much about TimeSeries, but I hope this helped a little.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I don't think it is a misuse of TimeSeries because I have similar code at two other places in code and it works perfectly. Only difference is that I use Scanner and while loop since I read values from text files at that places.

Comment: Are the values in "valuesFromArrayList" ever initialized outside of your for loop? Because if not, I suspect that the way the loop is constructed is the problem because it is making something write twice. Causing that error I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, I already checked values from ArrayList and they are fine. Also, this for loop works fine only when it is executed for the first time. When I change comboBoxValue, I get above mentioned message.

Comment: I also don't think it is problem of duplicate date, because as I said, I use this in two other places, and there I get no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop will always overwrite the value with an index of 0 on seriesArray.

What I mean is, the first time it will write to [0]
The second it will write to [0] then [1]

Is this intended?

I have not looked at the docs too much, but the message says 'the series already contains an observation for that time period.' I think that loop is not doing what you want it to do.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I am pretty sure that it only chooses one index value that is meant to be chosen. Can you explain why you think that when I choose another index, index 0 will be overwritten as well?